# loops in one loop,

Tags: infinite-loop

I'm new Mathematica user. I try for loop but it didnt work.
I used

```
For[Mi = 10^8 * Msun, Mi < 10^9 * Msun, 10^8 * Msun, 
  Print[fvv[10^15, 0.001, Mi, 9.454140999315537`*^22]]
]
```

fvv is my function which is dependent from M,Mdot,as and nu (nu=10^15)
where: Mi is my new variable

- Mbeg = 10^8 *Msun
- Msun=1.989*10^30
- Mend = 10^9 *Msun
- Mstep = 10^8*Msun

I want to make one loop which consist of 4 loops with 4 different variables

- dotMbeg = 0.5*Msun/yr
- dotMend = 5*Msun/yr
- dotMstep = 0.5*Msun/yr
- asbeg = 0.001
- asend = 0.901
- asstep = 0.1

and fourth will be *cosi*
Have anyone have a experience for loop like i would like to have?

Comment: Please format the question for readability. Click the edit link below the question. You will find formatting help on the right, and below the editing toolbar. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: Also, since you look like you are just starting out with MMA, you might be interested in [Alternatives to procedural loops and iterating over lists in Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/27951) and in [Why should I avoid the For loop in Mathematica?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134609/27951).

Comment: Hint: What is your intention with the third argument in `For`, which you wrote as `10^8 * Msun`?  If you are also new to programming, take a look at https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/

Comment: It is the first argument which I want to be in loop. Msun = 2*10^30.

Now i try `do` loop but maybe it doesnt work because i use a big number?

Comment: You're not increasing `Mi`. Try `For[Mi = 10^8*Msun, Mi < 10^9*Msun, Mi = Mi + 10^8*Msun, 
 Print[fvv[10^15, 0.001, Mi, 9.454140999315537`*^22]]]`.

Comment: have you considered using `Table[fvv[a,b,c,d],{a,a0,a1},{b,b0,b1},{c,c0,c1},{d,d0,d1}]` ?

Comment: Feyre thank you it work!
I have one more question. Can I change `For[Mi = 10^8*Msun, Mi < 10^9*Msun, Mi = Mi + 10^8*Msun, Print[fvv[10^15, 0.001, Mi, 9.454140999315537*^22]]]` 10^15 in fvv for range 10^12 to 10^18 because like you show loop for counts only for one point curve but I want curve between 10^12 to 10^18 can I make loop consist this value?

Comment: Wouter I didnt, why I should consider that? Can it help me?

Did you mean like this `Table[fvv[nu, 0.01, 1.9890000000000002`*^39, 
  9.454140999315537`*^22], {nu, 10^12, 10*18}, {as, asbeg, asend}, {M,
   Mbeg, Mend}, {dotM, dotMbeg, dotMend}]` ??